# Using counter, how can I continue counting after server crash?

Tags: go, prometheus

I wrote a naive client Prometheus in Go.

It just create a counter and increment it 3 times:

```
counter = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts {
    Name: "test_count_0",
    Help: "Just a test man, no worries",
})

counter.Inc() 
counter.Inc() 
counter.Inc()
```

In Prometheus tab I can see "3" on graph, using query "test_count_0", after run it. All good.

But, if I run client again, will appear another "3" on graph.

I was expecting "6" (I thought that using same name will automatically update previous counter).

How can I increment counter that already exists?
I just can't find the way to do it.

Comment: It seems like you need a general backup service. What about saving the counter value into a data base or other persistence storage options ever a few seconds? I am not familar with the library so it is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `rate()` function and friends automatically handle counter resets. It would be very rare that you would use the value of a counter directly in PromQL.

Comment: yeah, but, i want to restart counting from 3 not from 0 when restart go client.
How can i do it?

Comment: You can't, that is not how counters are intended to be used.